# XGBoost fails with GLIBCXX_3.4.26 not found error on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, gcc, glibc

I'm attempting to run some code that calls into XGBoost on a Ubuntu 18.04 machine. This code fails with `AttributeError: 'XGBoostCostModel' object has no attribute 'pool'`, with the root cause:

```
Error message(s): ["/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.26' not found (required by /root/anaconda/envs/spell/lib/libxgboost.so)"]
```

I know nothing about the C/C++ packaging toolchain. Running the following code fragment, suggested in some other answers to similar questions, returns the following:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBC
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_3.4.22
GLIBCXX_3.4.23
GLIBCXX_3.4.24
GLIBCXX_3.4.25
GLIBC_2.2.5
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.14
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.18
GLIBC_2.16
GLIBC_2.3.4
GLIBC_2.17
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

`GLIBCXX_3.4.26` does indeed seem to be missing from this list. However, I cannot figure out what `apt` command I need to run to get something recent enough. When I run `apt-get update && apt-get install libstdc++6` (no `sudo`, because this is in a Docker container) I am told:

```
libstdc++6 is already the newest version (8.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04).
```

Now what?

Answer (score 1):

A colleague suggested downgrading to an older version of `xgboost`. Doing so fixed this issue (using `xgboost==1.1.0`).

AFAICT this means that the latest versions of `xgboost` are incompatible with Ubuntu 18.04 because they use a version of the compiler toolchain that is too recent for and unsupported by 18.04.